# Fetch all table rows to array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I've been trying to figure out how to fetch all rows into an array and check if some input exists as an entry in that array.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$myarray = array();
$getnames = "SELECT NAME FROM PEOPLE";
$names = oci_parse($conn,$names);
oci_execute($names);
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($names)) != false) {
    $myarray[] = oci_fetch_row($names);
}

if(!in_array($name, $myarray)) {
      echo "That name doesn't exist.";
  }
```

In my table there are:

```
NAME
Fred
Bob
Hamlet
```

In the case that I used "Bob" as input, I used `var_dump($myarray)` just to see what was contained in that array:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "Bob" } [1]=> bool(false) }
```

With my output being:

```
That name doesn't exist.
```

The output is what I didn't expect it to be (as I expected "Bob" to be in the array),so I'm guessing that my method of fetching rows into an array isn't adequate.

What can I do in order for the rows to be fetched into an array?

Comment: `SELECT NAME` but your column is `NAMES` ?

Comment: My bad, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because Bob doesn't exist as a value in `$myarray`, but it's in `$myarray[0][0]`, ie. as a value in the first item of `$myarray`.

You need a function that recurses into the result arrays:

```
function recursive_in_array($needle, $haystack) {
    if (!is_array($haystack)) return false;
    $match = false;
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) $match = recursive_in_array($needle, $item);
        if ($match || in_array($needle, $haystack)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I only tested this quickly, but it should do the trick.

Comment: How would I be able to use this function? Like `if (recursive_in_array($name, $myarray)==true) { #do something }`

Comment: Exactly, or just `if (recursive_in_array($name, $myarray)) {`. Both do the same thing.